# Why ReactdataPicker stiles are not applied in a Wordpress React based plugin?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

to be on the save side I added two way:

1. import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'

is in the component.

And in `Admin.php` I have

```
    if ( $this->plugin_screen_hook_suffix == $screen->id || $screen->id == "tikex_page_tiket-on-wordpress-eventtimeseditor") {
        wp_enqueue_style( $this->plugin_slug . '-style-7', plugins_url( 'assets/css/ReactDatePickerFromNodeModules.css', dirname( __FILE__ ) ), array(), $this->version );
    }
```

I copied the css in mode_modules to `ReactDatePickerFromNodeModules.css`.

When using `react-datepicker`, style is not applied, but only in safari. Why?

Answer (score 0):

this issue:

Add the following code to your Admin.php file:

```
   if($screen->id == "tikex_page_tiket-on-wordpress-eventtimeseditor") {
        wp_enqueue_style( $this->plugin_slug . '-style-7', plugins_url( 'assets/css/ReactDatePickerFromNodeModules.css', dirname( __FILE__ ) ), array(), $this->version );
        wp_enqueue_style('react-datepicker', 'https://unpkg.com/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css');
    }
```

This will load the CSS file for react-datepicker directly from the unpkg CDN, which should fix the issue in Safari.